# Checking if element has active class full page js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu panel I would like to hide if section 1 is on display with full page js. So i was checking if the #section1 has class active, if it does then do not display sidePannal, if not then hide it. This is not working, is this the appropriate method or what I am trying to achieve?

```
if($('#section1').hasClass('active')){
    $('.sidePannel').css('display','none');
}

else{
    $('.sidePannel').css('display','block');
}
```

Comment: We have no way to know where you call this or what the page looks like. Please provide a [mcve]. The `else` is lacking an `if()` though and should be throwing error in browser console

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, i had an if else statement I forgot to remove the condition before uploading question

Comment: Ok, but still far too little known for anyone to provide assistance

Comment: Show us your html please!

Comment: i see what you mean, here is a link to fullpage js (page uses same layout): https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

#section1 is the top page, I am trying to hide an element while this section1 has class active, but when it no longer has this class, i am trying to show the element.

Comment: Just guessing: You don't use the event methods but added the code after initalizing fullpage?
Could you create a minimal jsfiddle (or similar) to show the problem?